# sysctl changes persist after removing conf file and reboot

Tags: centos, networking, sysctl

I have a package which installs a sysctl config file to */etc/sysctl.d* in order to "tune" some default settings.  For example, some are

```
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = agilesd
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 20
net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 0
```

The defaults for these are `cubic`, `60` and `1` (respectively).

I have a need where I must temporarily "disable" them.  That's simply accomplished by setting them to the default.  However, my experimentation lead me to moving the file `/etc/sysctl.d/99-my_ip_changes.conf` from that directory to `/root` and rebooting.  On one of the CentOS 7.6 systems on which this package is installed, after a reboot, things do in fact revert to the default.  However, on two others, they do not.  After a reboot, the TCP Congestion Algorithm is still `agilesd` for example.

I have verified, to the best that I can, that there is no other sysctl conf file setting these things to the same values set in this config file.  Can anyone help me in understanding why this is happening?

Comment: search for the word agilesd everywhere? :)

Comment: @rogerdpack Thanks, I'll have to give that a go.  :-)

Comment: Post an answer back when/if you figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you have a mistake in the sysctl fields names as they should start with 'net' and not with 'sys', like so:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = agilesd
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 20
net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 0
```

Besides that, from what I can tell the file '/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf' is actually a symbolic link to '/etc/sysctl.conf':

```
$ll /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 14 Dec 31 17:03 /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf -> ../sysctl.conf
```

So my guess is that on the systems that didn't revert the change the original file was changed and even after moving your file ('/etc/sysctl.d/99-my_ip_changes.conf') to '/root' the original file '/etc/sysctl.conf' was still holding the "tuned" values.

If you still having trouble with this issue please check this out. If not, maybe this would help someone else in the future.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are correct about the sysctl names.  I've corrected the error in my post.  I think you're probably correct.  I will be looking into this, this week.